# Releasing a java based git project using maven release command

Tags: java, git, maven

I have a Git project on Bitbucket and I am trying to release it using `mvn release:prepare` command but I am getting following exception.

I understand that it is asking for my password but not sure where and how to specify it.

**Error Log:**

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 20.355 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-10-20T12:17:04-04:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 13M/166M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.3.2:prepare (default-cli) on project git-cicd-demo: Unable to tag SCM
[ERROR] Provider message:
[ERROR] The git-push command failed.
[ERROR] Command output:
[ERROR] bash: /dev/tty: No such device or address
[ERROR] error: failed to execute prompt script (exit code 1)
[ERROR] fatal: could not read Password for 'https://nitalchandel@bitbucket.org': Invalid argument
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.study.git.cicd</groupId>
    <artifactId>git-cicd-demo</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <!-- VCS integration -->
    <scm>
        <connection>scm:git:https://nitalchandel@bitbucket.org/nitalchandel/git-cicd-demo.git</connection>
        <url>https://nitalchandel@bitbucket.org/nitalchandel/git-cicd-demo</url>
        <developerConnection>scm:git:https://nitalchandel@bitbucket.org/nitalchandel/git-cicd-demo.git</developerConnection>
    </scm>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.10</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.7.5.201505241946</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>report</id>
                        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>report</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: First use a newer version of [maven-release-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/) 2.5.2....

Comment: You can define your git password in your Maven Settings. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28282572/maven-release-plugin-git-credentials. By the way, you also can encrypt this password if you don't want it in plain text in a file.

Comment: @Gael - I have added the password in my settings.xml file but not sure how to reference it. How will it be picked up using mvn release:prepare command ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to specify your password on the command line:

```
mvn release:prepare -Dpassword=qwerty ...
```

See [here](http://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/prepare-mojo.html) for the full set of options for `release:prepare`.